# drupal_add_css does now work when in cache mode

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

I am trying to add a jquery plugin to a page through drupal_add_css and drupal_add_js as follows:

```
drupal_add_css($path = 'sites/all/libraries/gips/css/gips.css', $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = true);
drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/gips/js/gips.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 3));
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function(){...dosomething...});"), array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5));
```

When I'm not aggregating/caching the CSS files, it works fine.
When I try to aggregate the CSS files, it doesn't. The behavior is as if some css rules get lost in the process. 
The same happens even if I change the `$preprocess` to `false`.

From Chrome's code inspector, I cannot see any overriding rules getting in the way either.

I am at a loss on how to debug this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please take the time to accept the answers to your previous questions, people will be much more willing to help if you do :)

Comment: @Clive I am not sure which answers you are referring to. Is this a generic comment or you have something specific in mind? From what I looked, I have upvoted the answers I found useful.

Comment: @Clive Ahh! Much obliged. I wasn't aware of this. Will do right away!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you are using the version 7 drupal_add_js, the snippet you posted appears to be using the Drupal 6 arguments for [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7). You might also need to set the `every_page` option to true so that it is aggregated. Maybe try:

```
drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/gips/css/gips.css', array('type' => 'file', 'media' => 'all', 'preprocess' => true, 'every_page' => true));
```

You could also have a look at the group and weight settings on the api page linked above to see if they will help.

Answer (score 0):

For d7 with enabled aggregation needed `'preprocess' => FALSE` for css and js: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7

Comment: While broadly helpful if this is coming up in Google, this specific question does say "even if I change the `$preprocess` to `false`"